# Large Braids with Hair Particles

Tags: particles, properties

How could I take out the space in-between the hair strands on a large braid?

[image: Example]

I would like to remove those "holes" and make hair children better distributed. I tried reducing the amplitude, but it gets too skinny. As you can see on the settings it's 1 parent with 10k children particles.

[image: Settings]

I'm pretty sure I can make adding a **custom property**, but I don't know which one to choose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I had play with the **Children** settings till actually got some reasonable result:

[image: Large Braid]

Here is my recipe for a nicer looking braid:

- As you can see, mainly **Random** and **Size** properties made the strands get thicker, but it can also mess around with the shape at the end. So I suggest trim it with **Length**.
- Use a high value for **Clump** on **Effects Section** and a low **Clump** on **Kink Section**.
- If you get a fading effect like I was having on my question, try to change the **Shape** value to something like **-0.9** on **Cycles Hair Settings.**

[image: Settings]

Suggestions are very welcome.