# Blender braided beard

Tags: particles, hair

I'm trying to figure out how to do a braided beard (fantasy dwarvish'ish style, a bit like this: http://dariofish.deviantart.com/art/Dwarf-Braided-Beard-Test2-409580675).

I am trying out the particle hair. But I can't really make it behave. Here's my results so far:
[image]

A couple of things annoy me with this result:
1) Each individual strand looks too thick.
2) It's not braided very nice. 
3) The two braids go in a strange direction towards the screen (can't really see that from the picture).

The guy over here made some results I think look much more even:
[Large Braids with Hair Particles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19124/large-braids-with-hair-particles)
But if I try to replicate his settings it all gets much worse.

Does anyone have an idea what I may be missing in order to get closer to the other SE posters results? His braid looks nice and even and the hairs are much thinner.

Comment: I doubt that the braids in your first link are done using particles.

Comment: I agree. It was just to show what kind of result I was aiming for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Important stuff I missed was:

- Use Simple children instead of interpolated for this
- Lots of steps in render settings (using 9)
- Cycles Hair Settings -> Thickness to get better looking hair (subjective, I know)
- Other settings can be seen in image below.

[image]

Now I just need to figure out how to get rid of that fur-ball attached to the monkeys chin...